# How to find the disk that holds a given partition in C#?

Tags: c#, filesystems, disk

Does anyone know a way to find out programatically which physical disk holds a given partition?
Manually, I can find this info using Start->Run->diskmgmt.msc , where I can see that (on my computer) that partitions C: and D: are on disk 1, E: & F: on disk 0.

This is for optimizing some file crunching operations by doing them in parallel if the files are on different physical disks.

Comment: It sounds like you mean "logical disk" or "volume" and not "partition". Keep in mind a partition can be empty (have no volume on it) and a volume can reside on multiple partitions when spanning/striping across multiple disks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain this information using WMI from System.Management namespace by quering [Win32_DiskDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132(VS.85).aspx) class.

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257340(VS.80).aspx) basic info about WMI in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Arul's answer, here's a link that shows how to geth the disk<->partition association using WMI from a VBS script: [WMI Tasks: Disks and File Systems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394592.aspx)
-> see the last example on the page.

Edit: Even better, [here's a good article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/klaus_salchner@hotmail.com/WMIPart211162005021718AM/WMIPart2.aspx) on WMI using C#, which just happens to also describe the exact relationships between the WMI classes needed to get the disk drive (e.g. `\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0` ) that holds a logical disk (e.g. `C:`)

Answer (score 1):

see HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices

```
wmic path CIM_BasedOn get * > wmic-path-CIM_BasedOn-get.txt
wmic path CIM_DiskPartition get * > wmic-path-CIM_DiskPartition-get.txt
wmic path CIM_StorageExtent get * > wmic-path-CIM_StorageExtent-get.txt
```

see Class: CIM_BasedOn - non enumerate hiden partition, CIM_DiskPartition -all, but not see disk label, CIM_StorageExtent - GUID, label, partition(hide too)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the partition is associated with only one disk?  It could be striped/spanned/etc across multiple physical disks.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the possibility. I'm taking it one step at a time :)